# How would I code in MIPS the quotient of 2 registers without using quotient, modulus, or mul operators

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

I have to take the quotient of two registers. $t1 is equal to 49026 and $t3 is equal to 13122. This is my code, but it seems to give me an invalid value such as -47703. Please try to explain thoroughly with whats wrong with my code because I am very new to MIPS. If you have a better solution to this do not hesitate to show your example. If you need my entire code I will share as well. Thank You.

```
 Division: sub $t,$t1,$t3
 blt $t1, 0, END
 addi $t8, $t8, 1
 j Division
 END:
```

Comment: This program is so small you should be able to step through it line by line in the debugger.

Comment: asm operators like `%` or `/` only work on assemble-time constants, like `addi $t8, $zero, 15 / 7`.  You'd want a `div` *instruction* (but I think you mean you can't use that either.)

Comment: Are you using real MIPS with branch-delay slots, or MARS / SPIM with that disabled?  If you're on a MIPS with branch-delay slots, the instruction after END: might be running every iteration.  And BTW, you can use `blt $t1, $zero, END` because that's more efficient than an immediate 0.  What register holds `-47703`?  If it's `t8`, that's because you didn't zero it before the loop.

Comment: I am using MARS but in my project I am not allowed to use the div function. $t8 currently holds 0. @PeterCordes

Comment: I understand that the code itself is small as well but these few lines of code are part of a project where I must accept the user inputs and calculate their inputs in two different functions without using  {mul, mul.d, mul.s, mulo, mulou, mult, multu, mulu, div, divu, rem, sll, sllv, sra, srav, srl, srlv} OR Macro, Subroutines, or Functions. The values I gave are just output of the F function and G function that I was told to calculate. @RaymondChen

Comment: So set a breakpoint at the start of your function. When the breakpoint hits, single-step through your function to see why it calculates the values incorrectly. Or copy the function into a test harness that establishes the initial conditions manually.